# Probability of correctly declaring number as prime

Tags: probability, number-theory

It is known that a way to check whether a number $n$ is prime, is to check for divisors of $n$ from $2$ to $\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$. If we find any divisor, then $n$ is not prime. If we don't, then we don't need to check for divisors bigger than $\sqrt{n}$ (and $n$ is prime).

An "approximation" of this method would be to check for divisors the same way but from $2$ to $log_2n$. If we find any divisor we declare that $n$ is not prime. If we don't find any divisor we declare that $n$ is prime. Of course this method will not always give the correct results. My question is:

If the second algorithm declares a number to be prime, what is the probability that this number is actually prime?

Comment: For large numbers, lets say , $100$ - digit numbers many composites will be declared as prime. Which is the magnitude you are interested in ?

Comment: @Peter Large numbers is the magnitude I am interested in. Let $n$ be a random positive integer.(So it is almost always very large)

Comment: I upvoted this question in particular because it enlights that even massive trial division does not make the primality test of a huge number necessarily feasible. Even ruling out prime factors to $10^{50}$ would only increase the probability that we have a prime by factor $205$, hence a number of , lets say, $10\ 000$ digits would still have a very small chance to be prime. This is why finding huge primes is so difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For very large numbers we can estimate the probability as follows :

Let $N$ be the given number , then $M:=\frac{\ln(N)}{\ln(2)}$ is the limit of trial division.

Denote $$P:=\prod{\frac{p}{p-1}}$$ where $p$ runs over the primes upto $M$, if $M$ itself is very large, we can approximate this as $$P\approx \frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\ln(M)}$$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni-constant.

Then, the probability that we have a prime, if no factor is found, is roughly $$\frac{P}{\ln(N)}$$

For numbers $N\approx 10^{99}$ , we get about $4.6$%

Comment: Does this assume that the event that a number's least prime factor is greater than $\log_2 n$ is independent from the number being prime? If that fact is in any way correlated with a number being prime, the probability may not work out so cleanly, would it? How does one know the events are not correlated? (I am definitely not saying that this is incorrect, I am just curious if that is already part of the calculation).

Comment: @InterstellarProbe If $N$ is so large that the product of the primes upto the limit of the trial division is much smaller , then this probability will be near to the true probability. The probability for a "random" number to be prime is about $\frac{1}{\ln(N)}$ , and with the theorem of Bayes we can easily derive the probability given in my answer.

Comment: For $10^{99}$ , the product is in fact bigger than $N$, but still the dependecies between the small prime factors should not be too dramatic. I think, my approximation still works well.

Comment: Interesting. I never got too in depth with number theory, but it is very cool that works :). I'll have to think more on it.

Comment: Also note that in the case, there is a factor in the trial division range, the number is not prime (if $N$ is sufficiently large). Hence only the case that no factor is found is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $n$ is a random positive integer from $1$ to $N$.  By the Prime Number Theorem, the probability that it is prime is on the order of $1/\log N$.  On the other hand, for each
prime $p < \log N$ the probability that it is not divisible by $p$ is $1 - 1/p$, so the probability that it has no prime factors $< \log N$ is on the order of
$$ \prod_{p \le \log N} (1 - 1/p) \approx \exp \left( - \sum_{k=2}^{\log N} 1/(k \log k) \right) \approx \exp(- \log\log\log N) = \frac{1}{\log \log N}$$ 
Thus the probability that a number that passes the test is prime is on the order of
$$ \frac{\log \log N}{\log N} $$

Comment: In your answer you say "for each prime $p<log N$" but the question was about testing for divisors until $log_2 n$. I know that $log_2n=O(logn)$ but why does that mean that your checking for prime factors until $log N$ gives the same result to my question as testing for prime factors until $log_2 N$?

Answer (score 1):

The probability that $n$ is not divisible by $p$ is : $1-\frac{1}{p}$, then

The probability that $n$ is prime is :

$$\prod_{\substack{\log_2(n) < p \leq \sqrt{n} \\ \text{p prime}}} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p} \right)$$

Consider Mertens 3rd theoreme as $n \to +\infty$:

$$\prod_{\substack{p \leq n \\ \text{p prime}}} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right) \sim \frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\log(n)}$$

Then :

$$\prod_{\substack{\log_2(n) < p \leq \sqrt{n} \\ \text{p prime}}} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p} \right) \sim \dfrac{2 \log(\log_2(n))}{\log(n)}$$